# C++ virtual inheritance, virtual destructors, and dynamic_cast<void*>

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand why the second assert fails in the following code (in case it matters, using MSVC via Visual Studio 2019):

```
#include <cstdlib>

class grandparent
{
public:
    virtual ~grandparent() {};
};

class parent : public virtual grandparent 
{};

class child : public parent
{};

int main() 
{
    void* mem = malloc(sizeof(child));
    child* c = new (mem) child;
    assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(c) == mem); // ok
    std::destroy_at(c);
    assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(c) == mem); // fails
}
```

From my understanding, `dynamic_cast<void*>` on a pointer to a polymorphic type returns the address of the most derived type of that pointer. This works out just fine prior to destruction via `std::destroy_at`. However after destruction it no longer gives the pointer to the originally allocated memory, but I don't understand why.

So my questions are:

1. How does `dynamic_cast<void*>` work in getting the address of the most derived type of the given pointer?
2. What does the destructor do such that it changes what `dynamic_cast<void*>` returns?

In searching around and trying to educate myself I found the following blog post in a series about vtables: https://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part4/. In the blog post there is a brief bit on destructors that mentions:

> Here's a quick thought-exercise: why do destructors change the vtable pointer to point to the their own class’s rather than keep it pointing to the concrete class? Answer: Because by the time the destructor runs, any inheriting class had already been destroyed. Calling such class’s methods is not something you want to do.

From this, one guess I have is that `dynamic_cast<void*>` works by looking at the vtable for the given pointer and that, like the quote says, destructors change the vtable pointers when they're called. Is this correct? If so, I'd like to understand exactly what's happening underneath, so any explanation or resources for further reading in that regard would be appreciated.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<void*>(c)` causes undefined behavior after `std::destroy_at`.

Comment: Pretty sure your answer lies with answering what `std::destroy_at(c)` does

Comment: Really the only thing you should be doing with a pointer to a destroyed object is to assign it a new value, or use placement new to create an new object in its pointed to space.  I'm not sure if you can legally do anything else with it as it's like having an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Assigning to a destroyed object is a bad idea. Certainly for non-trivial types but technically also for trivial types as far as I know; even though implementations might not necessarily care about the latter. Not quite same as uninitialised pointer; you can for example compare the pointer with other pointers.

Comment: @eerorika I'm talking about assigning the pointer to a new object, not the opbject that was just destroyed.

Comment: @eerorika How?  They still have `mem` which they can use to free once they are all done.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, right never mind :)

Comment: @NathanOliver what made me ask this question was working on code for destructing and freeing memory for later use in calling a custom allocator. To properly mark the memory as free, the allocator required the same address it originally returned when allocating the memory be passed to its deallocate function. With polymorphic type pointers, I was calling deallocate with `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)`, since the pointer might have been cast at some point and thus not necessarily pointing to the original address. However this call was happening after destruction of the object via `std::destroy_at(p)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking how it works. You will not get a definite answer to that. The best one will be able to answer, authoritatively, is that after `std::destroy_at` it is UB to `dynamic_cast`. That's what the standard says and compiler writers can do as they darn please, as long as they respect the standard.

That said, you can reason about what is likely to happen, in practice.

```
std::destroy_at(c);
```

will not de-allocate memory. It can only modify the memory that was allocated by malloc.

```
dynamic_cast
```

should logically only look at the memory buffer. Short of local optimizations, the only place it can look is in the buffer allocated by malloc.

That gives you the tools to figure out what your implementation is doing. Printout `sizeof(child)` bytes of memory at location `c` immediately after the placement new. Then print the memory again after each step.

That will tell you what your implementation is doing. It won't guarantee anything about what other compilers/machines could do. But I guess you'll see a v-table pointer being reset to zero, during the destroy.

If I try the following on my compiler:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class grandparent
{
public:
virtual ~grandparent() {};
};

class parent : public virtual grandparent 
{};

class child : public parent
{
int x = 0x42;// just to see where this is in memory
};

void print(void* c, size_t size)
{
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)(((unsigned char*)c)[i]) << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(child));
child* c = new (mem) child;

print(c, sizeof(*c));

assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(c) == mem); // ok
std::destroy_at(c);

print(c, sizeof(*c));

assert(dynamic_cast<void*>(c) == mem); // fails
}
```

I get:

> 60 ab d7 0 42 0 0 0 58 ab d7 0
>
> 60 ab d7 0 42 0 0 0 34 ab d7 0
>
> Assertion failed: dynamic_cast(c) == mem, file
>
> d:\projects\test1\test1.cpp, line 41

So, there's some extra before the object. There's the storage for 0x42, three padding zeroes, and a pointer (this is the v-table, shown in the debugger). A pointer which gets modified during deletion and prevents the next dynamic_cast from working. One could then inspect the memory and figure out more.

**But nothing you find is guaranteed to hold on another implementation, or even at your next build.**

Comment: I wonder why the v-table pointer would be set to zero? It's an operation that will take time and shouldn't matter to the operation of the code.

Comment: Yeah. Same here. (see edit with details). But I'll dig and figure out what those two pointers are.

Comment: I think I figured out the answer to my own question - resetting the v-table pointer can help point out the error of calling virtual functions within a destructor. Obviously it would only be a courtesy on the part of the compiler, and maybe only in a debug build.

Comment: Actually, no, for some reason the vtpr of child gets modified to become the vptr of the grandparent. If you are to try std::destroy() twice (bad bad UB), the second time, the grandparent destructor is called directly.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd bet the vptr gets progressively changed to its parent after each destructor is called, all the way up and ends up staying at the last value it got. That would allow intermediate destructors to call virtual functions and have them called on somewhat valid objects.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for showing how to dig a bit deeper! This is exactly what I was looking for. One misunderstanding I held that this helped me realize is that destruction of an object might do more than just what it is in the destructor. In this case, it's modifying the Run-Time Type Information that `dynamic_cast<void*>` uses to do the cast to the most derived type. I understand that this is implementation specific, but it's helped me understand more about the metadata that may be stored alongside an object and how different operations might affect/use that metadata.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. How does `dynamic_cast<void*>` work in getting the address of the most derived type of the given pointer?

How `dynamic_cast` achieves its requirements is up to the particular implementation of the langauge. In practice, some data has to be stored alongside the object. This data is called *Run-Time Type Information*.

> 2. What does the destructor do such that it changes what dynamic_cast returns?

It destroys the object, of course. The lifetime of the object has ended. The behaviour of using `dynamic_cast` on a pointer to an object outside of the lifetime of the object is undefined (using it while destructing / constructing has special rules).

Standard says (quoting the latest draft)

> [basic.life]
>
> ... The lifetime of an object o of type T ends when:
>
> - if T is a class type, the destructor call starts
>
> ... after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, ... The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - ...
> - the pointer is used as the operand of a dynamic_­cast ([expr.dynamic.cast]).

Comment: Thanks for the quote of the standard, I need to get in the practice of looking at it whenever I have questions about how or why things are working the way they are. I was using [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) as my reference and didn't see a mention of `dynamic_cast` causing undefined behavior after the lifetime of an object.

Comment: I also, for some reason, didn't think that how `dynamic_cast` worked was up to the implementation of the language and not part of the language definition itself. This is something I'm still getting used to being a thing as well, so thanks for clearing that up too.